# LUAROCKS on windows installs rocks oddly

Tags: linux, windows, lua, luarocks

On Linux, luarocks installs rocks to

```
/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rock
```

and puts a corresponding lua file into

```
/usr/local/share/lua/5.3
```

On Windows(LUA 5.1), the rocks are in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\lib\luarocks
```

and the lua files are in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\share\lua\5.1
```

but lua cannot find them on the windows install.

I must have a PATH problem

This is some of my PATH:

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\;C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2;C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\lua\luarocks;C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\UnxUpdts;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs
```

I am trying ZeroBraneStudio as the IDE and my system prefs specify this path

```
path.lua = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1'
```

I ran

```
luarocks install inspect
```

and that generated the necessary files. Then I wrote this simple test code:

```
require "inspect"
assert(inspect(1) == "1")
assert(inspect("Hello") == '"Hello"')
```

and got this error

```
Program starting as '"E:\Anonamouse\ZeroBraneStudio\bin\lua.exe" -e "io.stdout:setvbuf('no')" "E:\Anonamouse\ZeroBraneStudio\myprograms\DemoInspectModule.lua"'.
Program 'lua.exe' started in 'E:\Anonamouse\ZeroBraneStudio\myprograms' (pid: 14776).
E:\Anonamouse\ZeroBraneStudio\bin\lua.exe: ...namouse\ZeroBraneStudio\myprograms\DemoInspectModule.lua:2: attempt to call global 'inspect' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...namouse\ZeroBraneStudio\myprograms\DemoInspectModule.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x00402a57
Program completed in 0.04 seconds (pid: 14776).
```

I get the same error when I execute the same simple app directly in the console.(That tells me that PATH variable for lua is working)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the error message you quoted the `require "inspect"` worked just fine, but the module didn't set a global variable `inspect`. For some time now it has been policy to *not* set globals from within modules, but instead return something (usually the module table) from the module code, which in turn gets passed down via `require`. So probably something like

```
local inspect = require "inspect"
assert(inspect(1) == "1")
assert(inspect("Hello") == '"Hello"')
```

or

```
local inspect = require "inspect"
assert(inspect.inspect(1) == "1")
assert(inspect.inspect("Hello") == '"Hello"')
```

should work.